# Filter a column if another column contains specific set of values using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

In the following data frame, I want to filter for the group that contains person "a", "b", and "c":

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
person = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "e"), class = "factor")), .Names = 
c("group", 
"person"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'group', we get the logical index by checking whether `all` the 'a', 'b', 'c' elements are `%in%` 'person' to get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(c('a', 'b', 'c') %in% person)], group]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, using the same methodology after grouping by 'person'

```
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   filter(all(c('a', 'b', 'c') %in% person))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
v1 <- rowSums(table(df)[, c('a', 'b', 'c')]>0)==3
subset(df, group %in% names(v1)[v1])
```

#### Update

If we want to return only `2` group using `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    filter(all(c('a', 'b', 'c') %in% person), all(person %in% c('a', 'b', 'c')))
```

Or with `n_distinct`

```
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   filter(all(c('a', 'b', 'c') %in% person), n_distinct(person)==3)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(c('a', 'b', 'c') %in% person) & uniqueN(person)==3], group]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I've never used all within filter like that, it's great. If I want to only return a, b, and c without any other person (e.g. group #4 is also returned with code as is), I'd filter on count of records returned to 3. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @John Did you meant to return `df %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(any(!person %in% c('a', 'b', 'c')))`